# How to expand unused space on usb key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, partitioning

My NAS runs Ubuntu Server 12.04, it runs this from an 8gb USB disk which is getting quite full so I have transferred that to a 32gb key using

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=512
```

Now, this is great, it now boots as it should - problem is that the new drive is reporting as being the same size

```
/dev/sdb1       6.4G  5.3G  837M  87% /media/f8772a74-ab0a-450c-9453-0ea91422051f
```

so i try

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb1
```

and get

```
The filesystem is already 1694208 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Soooo.. i try

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and get

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sdb1   *        2048    13555711     6776832   83  Linux
   /dev/sdb2        13557758    15632383     1037313    5  Extended
   /dev/sdb5        13557760    15632383     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Now I'm out of ideas - do i need to 'merge' sdb2 and sdb5 ?  what should i do to use the full space.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do i need to 'merge' sdb2 and sdb5 ? what should i do to use the full
>   space.

Yes, that's it, essentially. To use the available space you must:

- expand the partition
- then expand the file system

You used `resize2fs` correctly, but it cannot use more space than the partition provides, so the partition must be expanded first. You can do that with `fdisk` or `cfdisk`, or use some frontend like [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) (graphical) or [GNU Parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) (console).

Note that this case is a bit special because you have one [primary partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition) (sdb1) and one [extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) (sdb2) containing a logical partition (sdb5). You'll have to delete sdb2 (thus deleting sdb5 that lies inside), then expand sdb1.

*Note*: I hope I don't need to mention that before doing this, you should check that the backups which you certainly have are up-to-date and complete...

Also, *check what the other partitions contain before deleting them*.

Comment: DO NOT MERGE sdb2 and sdb5 - sdb2 is a "Virtual" partition to allow more then 4 primary partitions.

Comment: @davidgo: Thanks for the hint. I incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply copying the entire disk (or stick) from a lower capacity to a higher capacity does not take advantage of the larger size.  You'll need to first resize the partition, then resize the file system.  I'm a fan of Gparted http://gparted.org/